# PHP working different if the browser is Safari or Chrome

Tags: php, html, browser, html-table, cross-browser

I'm facing a problem I didn't even thought could ever happen. Basically the PHP script of the page run some login thing and then decide in a table whatever a `<td>` must or mustn't have specific classes. Now if I run the script, the PHP run badly returning no class when a `<td>` must have that class. On Chrome instead the class is there as it should. I tried to close both the browsers and then reload the page multiple times, but it seems that in Chrome and Safari the PHP script behave differently, how could it be possible?

What should I look at when happens such a thing?

**PS**

I'm not posting the PHP script in first instance because it is a very fragmentary script and gaining the entire script here would means thousands of line of code (notice that only the calendar script is 100+ lines). Also I think it's not a script related problem.

Comment: It is going to be *impossible* to figure out what is going on here without seeing the code.  Period.

Comment: Have you tried it on multiple machines or adobe browserlab and similar testing sites?

Comment: I do not understand what your script is doing and in what context you are determining the class. Maybe show the relevant code fragments

Comment: You're correct that the browser shouldn't have any impact. Assuming you're POSTing or GETing the login - can you var_dump $_GET and $_POST? Including at least some of the code will help. Don't think we have enough to go on atm.

Comment: Agreed, can you at least post the output on each browser in full if not the PHP?

Comment: I think your script may be outputting malformed HTML. Try running it through a validator  to catch any potential problems

Comment: Without any code to work with, the only thing I can guess is a caching issue. "When you see hoof-prints, think horses not zebras."

Comment: View your page, then view the souce, and copy and paste the ENTIRE html output to http://validator.w3.org/unicorn/#validate-by-input+task_conformance under the direct input. This will tell you if the html is mal-formed, which is likely a cause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By the time the browser gets your page the PHP has been executed, so there can't be any difference in how different browser "handle" PHP (because they simply don't).  You could have other problems, maybe malformed HTML (forgotten quote, misplaced tags etc.), so posting some of that PHP code would be the only way to tell.

Comment: Just technically there could be a difference - if it was looking at submitted data and doing something with it. For example, you could write HTML conditionally based on User-Agent, presence of a cookie or session variable, etc.

Comment: @Blowski - good point, well made. But this one really looks like a script related problem ;-)

Comment: @GaryBarnett agreed, it was more of a statement from Pedant's Corner than a probable answer.